# When staying in a US hotel, should I tip the housekeeping?

Tags: hotels, tipping

I grew up outside the US, and in our culture,
tipping almost never ever happens.

I am aware that when eating at a restaurant in the US,
you are expected to tip between 15-20%.

When I stay in a hotel in the US,
am I expected to tip the housekeeping?
Why or why not?

Comment: Wikitravel lists 4-5$/day, a travel guide of mine that is a bit older lists USD 2/night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people don't tip at all in hotels, others give a single dollar a day. Of course, the people cleaning your room don't get a lot of pay, and love to see tips, but there is no strong obligation like in full service restaurants.